# Is it possible to get the textScore on mongodb MapReduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

If you created a textIndex on mongodb 2.6 when you `find` or use the pipeline `aggregate` framework you can get the `textScore` given a query with the projection:

```
{'$meta': "textScore"}
```

This allows to operate with the textScore in further operations.

Is it possible to acces such value during a map-reduce operation?

Comment: As at MongoDB 3.0, there is no option to invoke [text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) from MapReduce. I suspect this is unlikely to be added, as the [Map/Reduce paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) is quite different from iterating results in a `find` or `aggregate` query. You always have the option of first aggregating into a collection with `$out` and then running M/R on that collection, but that may be unnecessary overhead. Can you explain your M/R use case further? In general use of the aggregation framework is encouraged for best performance.

Comment: I wonder if I can use the 'text lenght' to improve my results on a recomendation system. With Map-reduce I can calculate the text length easy an preform tets. If results are better then I can add the field on DB and use pipeline. Without map-reduce I need to add a new value in all the documents without know if it deserves.

Comment: If you don't want to add a new field until after performing some experiments, I would suggest testing by manipulating the `find()` or `aggregate()` results in your application code. If you have multiple fields in your text index you may also want to experiment with [field weight](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/). For example, you could put more weight on matches found in a title/summary field than a longer body/description field.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no string length operator in the aggregation framework (as at MongoDB 3.0) but you could upvote and/or watch [SERVER-5319](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5319) in the MongoDB issue tracker. There are surprisingly few votes for this feature so far :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will probably create some toy db to preform experiments. BTW I updated it :)